# Make class in swift3 with AVplayer

Tags: avplayer

this is the code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MP3PLAYER {

    var player = AVPlayer()

    func PLAY (){

       player.play()

    }

    init ( url_ : String , autoplay_ : String , player_ : AVPlayer) {

       player = player_

       let url = url_

       let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( url:URL( string:url )! )
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
        player.rate = 1.0;


        if autoplay_ == "YES" {
        player.play()
            print("autoplay is on")
        }

   }
}
```

In this code there is no error even warning.

Simply player wont play . If i put code direct in viewController than player working ...

I use class on this way in viewController:

```
<code>
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class Mp3Stream_example: UIViewController {
    var player = AVPlayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     let STREAM1 = MP3PLAYER(url_: "http://listen.181fm.com:181-soul_128k.mp3" , autoplay_: "YES" , player_ : player )
     STREAM1.player.play()
     //player.play()   
     .....
 </code>
```

Comment: Apart from creating the `AVPlayer`  a few too many times, this code should work fine. How are you using it? Are you sure `MP3PLAYER` isn't going out of scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player, `STREAM1`, is going out of scope and is being deallocated, hence no sound. Make it a class member variable instead of a local variable. e.g.

```
class Mp3Stream_example: UIViewController {
    let STREAM1 = MP3PLAYER(url_: "http://listen.181fm.com:181-soul_128k.mp3" , autoplay_: "YES" , player_ : AVPlayer() )
     ....
```

P.S. you've got extra `AVPlayer`s that you don't need.

Comment: Ok , even this is not necessary  , player_ : AVPlayer() . I need class structure to make all simple. Swift is much better than ObjC but  still complex, like observeValue for AVplayer etc...